# Youtube to MP3 Convert - Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, youtube, mp3

I'm wondering if I can create an application that converts a youtube link to mp3 and save it on a desktop. Does anyone have any suggestions to do this? Any references of links?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean capturing video - extracting a soundtrack from it and save it as an mp3? There are tools for doing just that called `audio extractors`. It's possible that some of these are available as libs. Here's [link to one of the tutorials](http://bestvideoconvertersoftware.blogspot.com/2009/04/share-my-way-of-free-download-videos.html) that may give you some ideas

Answer (score -1):

You could have a look at how the [Easy YouTube Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10137) does it.

Answer (score -1):

Try [KissYouTube](http://kissyoutube.com/). Extract the audio stream from the flv file to whatever audio format you want.